# Error when Count rows from 2 Tables in Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to count the number of rows from 2 tables based on my terms, in Microsoft Office Access 2007, but when I ran the SQL statement, I got this message :

> "the microsoft office access database engine cannot find the input
>   table or query 'dual'. make sure it exist and that its name is spelled
>   correctly"

I got this method from the internet. Here is my SQL statement :

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Data_Kontrak
        WHERE NOT (
                (month(Tanggal_Berakhir_Izin)) <= month(now)
                AND NOT (year(Tanggal_Berakhir_Izin)) <= year(now)
                )
        ) AS Count1
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Kontrak
        WHERE NOT (
                (month(Tanggal_Akhir)) <= month(now)
                AND NOT (year(Tanggal_Akhir)) <= year(now)
                )
        ) AS Count2
FROM dual
```

Comment: pick mysql or sql server

Comment: `dual` is a special virtual table used in Oracle databases, which I guess your code was written for. It is not available in MS Access so you need to adapt your query accordingly.

Comment: then how can i use the same method in Microsoft Office Access? Help please

Comment: Just  delete `FROM dual`

Comment: thank you for the responses, i deleted `FROM dual` but i got this error message : "Query Input must contain at least one table  or query"